# Android Widget - One action, multiple buttons

Tags: android, events, button, android-widget

I'm completely new to Android and I'm developing a widget that has multiple buttons. The action that must be taken for each of these buttons is logically the same. The only thing I would need is to know which button was clicked. Do I have to use different `Action`s and set them to an `Intent` for every Button or is there a more efficient way? I tried to create custom buttons with [custom XML attributes](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/) but that seemed too complicated and flexible for this purpose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Button's onClick attribute to specify a method in the host activity that will be called when the button is called This method will pass in a View object as a parameter which is the button that was clicked, based on which you can change your logic as required.

Comment: Specify `android:onClick` in your button tag when you define it in your axml layout file.

Comment: I thought you can't use the onClick event in widgets. I tested it, and the widgets stop working as soon as I add the onClick event. BTW, I've added the clicked method to the WidgetProvider, is that wrong?

Comment: That's weird. The onClick attribute is a convenience attribute at the end of the day, you can always resort to implementing the click listener interface. Take a look at the sample code at the top of [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) You can set the same on click listener for both buttons.

Comment: I checked the page. The thing is, I have one Activity for my app and a WidgetProvider for my widget. The sample in the link is using an Activity which the widget doesn't have. Am I making a mistake here?